# Node + Mongo: Utilizing an index in sorting

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection I want to search to find the oldest [changed] document where [enabled] is true. In anticipation of this I have ensured that the [changed] field is indexed.

Would the following make use of this index?

```
records.findOne({enabled:true}, {sort:[['changed', 'asc']]}, function(error, record) {
```

The documentation *appeared* to me to suggest I need to have filtered on the index in order for it to be useful in the sort. Would the addition of a (otherwise superfluous) filter on [changed] work better?

```
records.findOne({changed:{$gte:0}, enabled:true}, {sort:[['changed', 'asc']]}, function(error, record) {
```

Answer (score 1):

An Index can also be used only for sorting even if you not filtered on the index before. However using the index in your filter could speed up your query because you can reduce the scanned dataset more quickly.

You should use an [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on both queries to verify which one is better.

Comment: Thank you (not sure if I am supposed to mark this as answered but I don't see an option to do so).